# An Artin's exercise revisited

Tags: group-theory, permutations

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200333/subgroups-of-s-4-that-contain-the-kernel-of-a-homomorphism-varphis-4-to?rq=1) post (and many other similar to it) we can see the $6$ subgroups of $S_4$ containing the $K=\text{Ker}(\phi)$ are: $$\{K, \text{Stab}(\Pi_1), \text{Stab}(\Pi_2), \text{Stab}(\Pi_3), A_4, S_4\}$$

So far so good, also letting me to learn an action Kernel is the intersection of the sets underlying the stabilizers, which is cool indeed.

Now I came to yet another similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893360/subgroups-of-s4) in which a comment claims:

> The subgroups of $S_4$ containing $\text{Ker}(\phi)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of $S_3$

I've tried to understand this using some intuition. For example $K \cong V_4$, and this is normal in all the six subgroups above.

Taking the quotient from all of them I got six subgroups with order $1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6$.

This is exactly the order of the subgroups of $S_3$.

Can my guess be correct?

Can my guess be related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62468/interpretations-of-the-correspondence-theorem-4th-isomorphism-theorem), somehow? (I came to this just while completing this question, so sorry if it was the answer, since I was not aware of the correspondence thm while evolving my guess above).

This is for self-learning and not a school problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the correct link (first one)? It goes to a question that does not mention $S_4$ or $\phi$...

Comment: The correspondence is the Fourth (or "Lattice") Isomorphism Theorem. The subgroups of $\mathrm{Im}(\psi)$ are in one to one, inclusion preserving, normality preserving correspondence with the subgroups of $G$ that contain $\ker(\psi)$ for any group homomorphism with domain $G$.

Comment: I fixed the wrong link, @ArturoMagidin. So taking the quotient as I did can be a good attack plan? I'll check if this is part of the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: I mean, just taking the quotient as I did is giving back $6$ subgroups isomorphic to the $6$ subgroups of $S_3$. And this without disturbing the $4^{\text{th}}$ isomorphism theorem, I guess. is that enough? This was my above question, indeed.

Comment: I Just saw from the last link you already answered to this question, provided $\phi$ Is onto $S_3$, which Is the case here. So I guess my intuition Is correct, even if not formally proven.

Comment: Yes , I already voted for closing this as duplicate